# Can IE Developer Tools be configured to 'see' a window that is less than full screen in size?

Tags: internet-explorer-dev

I have used Developer Tools for IE for over 2 years, so I have some good experience with the tool. But the window that I need to debug now is less than a full screen in size and cannot be made larger. (Just imagine a large window that is approximately 2/3's of your full screen, but cannot be enlarged so that it is full screen).  So when I try to utilize Developer Tools to debug the window, it doesn't work. It is as if Developer Tools tries to look at the full screen which is displayed behind my window that is displayed on the screen. Is there any way to make Developer Tools 'see' a window that is less than full screen in size and sits on top of another screen / web page?

Comment: (Please don't tell me that Microsoft is now moving to a maximized-windows-only approach in *older* software as well?)

Comment: What version of IE? Windows? What makes you say it "Doesn't work"? Error messages?

Comment: When I say 'doesn't work' here is what I mean:  When I click on the pointer of Developer Tools and then navigate to the window that is displayed, you can see the blue lines 'behind' or underneath my window.  Remember, this window is only about 40-60% the size of my full screen and CANNOT be enlarged to be full screen.  Apparently, Developer Tools is 'tied' to my full screen, and will not associate it's self with the smaller window that is displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Just follow the steps:
1) Open your webpage in IE (either it is maximize or not)
2) Click on webpage and press F12 key
3) Developer tool will appear.

Now, please make sure that developer tool is not maximized.

Note: Developer tool is only available for IE8 and above.